# Where are all the islands?

Tags: treasure-adventure-game

After obtaining the essential adventure items, the game quickly throws you in the deep end by opening up almost all the islands, and you must backtrack repeatedly looking for maps, treasure and items. Unfortunately it's easy to get lost or not know where to go. Yes, maps + compass tells you where one particular thing is, but not when you want to go somewhere else.

Is there a list of islands, their sequence, their names, and preferably a short descriptor (e.g. the one with the huge tree)?

Comment: The map... probably not, but if you are badly stuck, [the walkthrough](https://jayisgames.com/review/treasure-adventure-game.php#walkthrough) could possibly help you.